# Switching mobile app traffic from http to https

Tags: ios

I have a mobile app that communicate with ubuntu (AWS) production server over `http`.

We now would like to switch traffic over `https` and our apps on the stores are hard coded with the domain on `http`. Now we are about to release an updated set of app with the same domain hardcoded as `https`.

The issue is now with users who have already using the old app once we make changes live the will no longer be able to communicated with the server on `https` (the server is forced to listed to `port 443`). On the other hand users who are going to download the new app will be might be also not being able to communicate with the server in during the time we switch the traffic to `https`.

**My question:**

> Is there any way we can have both traffic enabled so both
>   users of the old and the new app can communicate with the server
>   before and after the change to `https`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why dont you redirect  http:// to https:// forcefully ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How can I do that? Can it be done on the server or app level?

Comment: I have the app statically hardcoded and pointed to http:// so I have no way to edit the app while installed on users phones. Is it still doable in this case to forcefully redirect traffic to https://?

Comment: that needs to be done at server level. few lines at .htaccess file and you will be done. What that will do is, it will redirect calls from http:// to https:// meaning you need not change anything in your app.

Comment: I am running LAMP stack, would you please be able to advise the commands/script that I need to run to shiver that? Much appreciated!

Comment: Just saw the commands. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem :) Please accept the answer by ticking the right arrow for the answer. Also, as a good coding practise donot hard code your urls, instead manage them in a single file and call them using getters from corresponding ViewControllers ;)

Comment: I accepted the answer and agree with you on the URL thing. Question, how can I contact you for work purposes?

Comment: Please share your email, will drop you a mail :)

Comment: Karwa.iq@gmail.com

Comment: noted.
Please delete the comment above ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need to do
[Redirect http to https](https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/apache/redirect-http-to-https)

You can check this link as well
[Apache Rewrite Http to Https](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS)